# Group by dynamic time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

For my problem I'll try to create a simplified example.
Table "order":

```
ID |    date    | client | product | product_limit_period (in months)
1  | 2015-01-01 | Bob    | table   | 1
2  | 2015-01-31 | Bob    | table   | 1
3  | 2015-02-01 | Bob    | table   | 1
4  | 2015-01-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
5  | 2015-06-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
6  | 2016-01-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
7  | 2016-12-31 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
```

This is the result, I'd like to get:

```
client | product | group | count
Bob    | table   | 1     | 2       #ID 1, 2
Bob    | table   | 2     | 1       #ID 3
Mary   | lamb    | 3     | 2       #ID 4, 5
Mary   | lamb    | 4     | 2       #ID 6, 7
```

Every product has a limit and a limit period (in months). I need to be able to see if there are any clients that have ordered a product more than its limit allows in a certain period. **The period in months might be 1 month or several years in months.** It is possible that the period is 1 month, 12 months, 24 months, ... until 108 months (9 years).

I feel like I need to use some combination of window functions and group by. But I haven't figured out how.

I'm using postgres 9.1. Please let me know if there is any more information I should provide.

Any help is appreciated, even just pointing me to the right direction!

**Edit:**
To clarify how the grouping works: The limit period starts with the first order. Bob's first order is 2015-01-01 and so this period ends with 2015-01-31. 2015-02-01 starts a second period. **A period always starts with the first day of a month and ends with the last day of a month.**

Comment: Why did you group `#ID 1, 2` together, but not `#ID 2, 3`? 2 & 3 also have less than month difference. If you want to find distinct groups, you'll have a hard time. Instead please describe the `product` table with the `limit` column. Finding only those who violated your limit constraints (but without distinct groups) is easy.

Comment: The limit period starts with the first order. Bob's first order is 2015-01-01 and so this period ends with 2015-01-31. 2015-02-01 starts a second period.
A period always starts with the first day of a month and ends with the last day of a month. I'll add this in my question as well, thanks!

Comment: so, if a first order was on `2015-03-15` and the `product_limit_period` is `12` (or more than a year), then the period still starts on the first day of the actual **month**? (`2015-03-01` in my example).

Comment: @pozs yes you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

no need to complicate with both window and group by, just add `case` to either a window or group, like here:

```
t=# select
  client
, product
, count(1)
, string_agg(id::text,',')
from so44
group by
  client
, product
, date_trunc(case when product_limit_period = 1 then 'month' else 'year' end,date);
  client  |  product  | count | string_agg
----------+-----------+-------+------------
  Bob     |  table    |     2 | 1,2
  Bob     |  table    |     1 | 3
  Mary    |  lamb     |     2 | 4,5
  Mary    |  lamb     |     2 | 6,7
(4 rows)
```

**sample:**

```
t=# create table so44 (i int,"date" date,client text,product text,product_limit_period int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy so44 from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1  | 2015-01-01 | Bob    | table   | 1
>> 2  | 2015-01-31 | Bob    | table   | 1
3  | 2015-02-01 | Bob    | table   | 1
4  | 2015-01-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
5  | 2015-06-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
6  | 2016-01-01 | Mary   | lamb    | 12
7  | 2016-12-31 | Mary   | lamb    | 12>> >> >> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 7
```

Comment: Hm, okay. But what if the period is several years. At the moment my system allows 1 month, 12 months, 24 months ... until 108 months (9 years)

Comment: I believe you should have told that in your question, before people try to help you :)

Comment: In my question I said "The period in months might be 1 month or several years in months.". I am sorry if it was written so that it was easily missed. I'll edit my question and make it in bold. Thank you for your help - can this solution be used with more than two different periods?

Comment: and answering your notice - logic does not change - you have to make an artificial comparison column as I did with `case`. btw if you can influence process, I'd go for two columns - startdate and endate instead to compare against